# Does a MicroControllers resistance change with computation?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, resistors, switches, resistance

Does the load resistance of a micro-controller change based on particular programs or instructions that it is currently running? Does adding in extra functionality of the device also have an effect on the resistance, such as Timers, ADC, Interrupt Service Routines etc?

For a follow up question, I see in a lot of the electrical characteristic sections of uC datasheets that higher frequency requires more current from the supply source. What is the actual cause of that? Shouldn't the overall current draw be unaffected by the clock speed? That is to say, on average, if I've got a program that spends half the time executing x instruction and the other half of the time executing y instruction, speeding that process up doesn't change the relative proportions of time spent in the different states. From the datasheets I've seen, it's not a 1-1 relationship, so doubling the speed won't double the current draw. So is it correct to assume that it's got to do with switching losses in the digital gates?

Comment: While alex.forencich's answer is great, you may want to wait some time before accepting an answer to encourage others to answer as well. That results in additional information and potential discussions.

Comment: Sure. Will do. Hopefully some others will come and get some more information.

Comment: Different instructions will consume slightly different amounts of power, but the real savings (such as what makes battery powered systems viable) comes with a software architecture that either lowers the clock and/or suspends the processor when there is no important work that needs doing or when a high clock rate is unecessary.

Comment: When it comes to power savings, there are all sorts of techniques that you can use.  DVFS (dynamic voltage and frequency scaling) is one where the CPU clock and core voltage are adjusted on-the-fly to meet software demands.  This gets you a 'triple-whammy' savings in frequency and voltage squared, as well as some savings in leakage current.  There are other considerations, though.  It takes an appreciable amount of time to put a core to sleep and wake it back up, so there is a trade-off between running for longer at low speed or sleeping for longer and then waking up and running at full speed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't really think about a microcontroller in terms of resistance.  It's built with transistors, and these do not behave like resistors.

Generally, most microcontrollers (and most highly-integrated digital logic) are CMOS devices.  This means that all of the logic gates inside are built out of complementary pairs of N-channel and P-channel MOSFET transistors.  One characteristic of CMOS logic is that it consumes the most power when switching.  This is because the transistor gates look like capacitors, and these capacitors have to be charged up whenever the logic level is changed.  At idle, little power is drawn.  The power consumed during switching is called dynamic power.  The general formula for CMOS dynamic power consumption is P = C * V^2 * f.  So the power consumed is proportional to the capacitance of the traces and transistor gates, the frequency, and the square of the voltage.  Now, this is not the complete story - there will also be some leakage current that makes its way through the transistors.  The leakage current increases with higher supply voltage, and it increases as the transistors get shrunk down on newer processes.

Any component inside of the chip that switches will consume power.  So yes, any peripherals that are enabled will increase power consumption.  Different processor instructions will consume different amounts of power as they will activate different logic.  Even the data being processed can have an effect on power consumption.  This is why it is possible in some cases to recover cryptographic keys by looking at the power consumption during computation.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to alex.forencich's fine answer, most peripherals in the microcontroller are connected to external circuitry, i.e. I/O ports, I²C, SPI, UARTs, USB, ADC, DAC, etc.  In addition to the power used internally to run the peripheral, there will be power consumed as the the peripherals either source (drive high) or sink (drive low) the pins connected to the external circuitry.

This is most evident in the case of I/O ports, where each pin may sink or source a maximum of, say, 25 mA (this number will vary depending on the microcontroller family, or even on a microcontroller basis).  However, you usually can't have all I/O pins driving pins at their maximum; to avoid overheating the chip there will also be a maximum value sunk by all I/O ports, say 200 mA, and another value for all current sourced by I/O ports; these values will be lower than the number of I/O pins times the maximum per pin.

Other peripheral pins, such as the serial ports (I²C, SPI, UART and USB), ADC, and DAC if present typically don't sink or source very much current.

Comment: So is it unlikely to be possible to drive all I/O ports high simply because of the current limitations? Could I for instance have all pins connected to low current applications like gates of a FET or BJT and have them High?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can't have all I/O pins driving at *maximum* at the same time.  It is okay for all I/O pins to be high, as long as the total current drawn is less than the allowed overall maximum.  Driving gates of FETs, for  example, requires practically no current at all, since unlike BJTs, they are voltage-controlled devices.  If all your I/O pins were driving the bases of BJTs, you would want to limit the current of each to a milliamp or two.